# how to create array of object inside object in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to create array of object of product sizes inside array of object of product info.

this is the HTML tree I am trying to scrape

```
<div class="product-thumbShim"></div><a target="_blank" href="tshirts/herenow/herenow-men-black-printed-round-neck-t-shirt/4318138/buy" style="display: block;"><div class="product-imageSliderContainer"><div class="product-sliderContainer" style="display: block;"><div style="background: rgb(244, 255, 249);"><div style="height: 280px; width: 100%;"><picture class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"><source srcset="
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_1.0,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg ,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_1.5,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 1.5x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_1.8,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 1.8x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_2.0,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 2.0x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_2.2,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 2.2x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_2.4,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 2.4x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_2.6,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 2.6x,
    https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,dpr_2.8,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg 2.8x" type="image/webp"><img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_2,q_60,w_210,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/4318138/2018/5/4/11525433792765-HERENOW-Men-Black-Printed-Round-Neck-T-shirt-2881525433792598-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="HERE&amp;NOW Men Black Printed Round Neck T-shirt" title="HERE&amp;NOW Men Black Printed Round Neck T-shirt" style="width: 100%; display: block;"></picture></div></div></div></div><div class="product-productMetaInfo"><h3 class="product-brand">HERE&amp;NOW</h3><h4 class="product-product">Men Printed Round Neck T-shirt</h4><h4 class="product-sizes"><!-- react-text: 396 -->Sizes: <!-- /react-text --><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">S, </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">M, </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">L, </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">XL, </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">XXL</span></h4><div class="product-price"><span><span class="product-discountedPrice"><!-- react-text: 405 -->Rs. <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 406 -->374<!-- /react-text --></span><span class="product-strike"><!-- react-text: 408 -->Rs. <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 409 -->749<!-- /react-text --></span></span><span class="product-discountPercentage">(50% OFF)</span></div></div></a><div class="image-grid-similarColorsCta product-similarItemCta"><span class="myntraweb-sprite image-grid-similarColorsIcon sprites-similarProductsIcon"></span><span class="image-grid-iconText">VIEW SIMILAR</span></div><div class="product-actions "><span class="product-actionsButton product-wishlist " style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><!-- react-text: 416 -->wishlist<!-- /react-text --></span></div><div class="product-sizeDisplayDiv"><div class="product-sizeDisplayHeader"><span>Select a size</span><span class="myntraweb-sprite product-sizeDisplayRemoveMark sprites-remove"></span></div><div class="product-sizeButtonsContaier"><button class="product-sizeButton">S</button><button class="product-sizeButton">M</button><button class="product-sizeButton">L</button><button class="product-sizeButton">XL</button><button class="product-sizeButton">XXL</button></div></div>"
```

adn this is my current output

```
[
 {
    brandName: 'max',
    productName: 'Colourblocked Round Neck T-shirt',
    productSizes: 'Sizes: S, M, L, XL, XXL'
  },
  {
    brandName: 'YOLOCLAN',
    productName: 'Printed Round Neck T-shirt',
    productSizes: 'Sizes: S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL'
  },
  {
    brandName: 'Maniac',
    productName: 'Colourblocked Hooded T-shirt',
    productSizes: 'Sizes: S, M, L, XL'
  }
]
```

and my expected output is

```
[
 {
    brandName: 'max',
    productName: 'Colourblocked Round Neck T-shirt',
    productSizes: [
             Size: 'S',
             Size: 'M',
             Size: 'L',
    ]
  }
]
```

current code :

```
const res = await page.$$eval(".product-base", (productInfo) =>
    productInfo.map((product) => {
        return {
            brandName: product.querySelector(".product-brand").innerText,
            productName: product.querySelector(".product-product").innerText,
            productSizes: product.querySelector(".product-sizes").innerText,
        };
    }),
);
```

and also how often I can scrape websites in order to not get my IP blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const res = await page.$$eval(".product-base", (productInfo) =>
    productInfo.map((product) => {
        let productSizeText = product.querySelector(".product-sizes").innerText;
        let productSizeArr = productSizeText.replace('Sizes:', '').trim().split(',');
        return {
            brandName: product.querySelector(".product-brand").innerText,
            productName: product.querySelector(".product-product").innerText,
            productSizes: productSizeArr,
        };
    }),
);
```

Comment: can u pls do one more help

Comment: @Sagar Chavan what is it?

Comment: ive edited the question

i am unable to get the image url out of it

Comment: on browser console it shows but, in code it's outputing asnull

Comment: @SagarChavan Stack overflow norms are you have one question at a time. Could you please post a new question with the details info as it is not clear hear? The HTML you shared needs formatting as well. I will help you one a new question that you post

Comment: are you scraping `source` tag URLs?

Comment: yess. Bt can u pls answere coz i;ll have to wait for another couple of hours for it then

Comment: post a question I am available to answer it. and answer my last comment too.

Answer (score 1):

Second answer for the HTML URLs: Using `Puppeteer.js` you can get the source tag URLs like below:

```
let imageURLArr = await page.evaluate(() => {
    //This will get the first sourceTag of the DOM, change the value 0 according to your DOM that you are scraping if it has more source tags and is not the first source tag element
    let sourceTag = document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
    // check selector exists
    if (sourceTag) {
        // This will give you all the image URLs of source tag
        let imagURLs = sourceTag.getAttribute('srcset')
        return imagURLs;
    }
});

console.log(imageURLArr);
```

Comment: I need to the imageUrl in the above object along with brandName,sizes and all is it possible ?

Comment: @SagarChavan Please post a new Question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204633/unable-to-get-url-inside-existing-object-using-puppeteer my new question